# Apache spark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column that has int values,

```
 2,43,1,25,3,13
```

How do I create another column which has , multiply first two values and then next two and so on..

```
null,86,null,25,null,39
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('MyApp').getOrCreate()
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([2, 43, 1, 25, 3, 13]).zipWithIndex()
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema=['int_val', 'idx']).cache()
df_r = df.select(df['int_val'].alias('int_val_r'), (df['idx'] + 1).alias('idx_r'))
df = df.join(df_r, on=[df['idx'] == df_r['idx_r']], how='left_outer').orderBy(df['idx'])
df = df.withColumn('res', f.when(df['idx'] % 2 == 1, df['int_val'] * df['int_val_r']).otherwise(f.lit('null')))
df.show()
```

output:

```
+-------+---+---------+-----+----+                                              
|int_val|idx|int_val_r|idx_r| res|
+-------+---+---------+-----+----+
|      2|  0|     null| null|null|
|     43|  1|        2|    1|  86|
|      1|  2|       43|    2|null|
|     25|  3|        1|    3|  25|
|      3|  4|       25|    4|null|
|     13|  5|        3|    5|  39|
+-------+---+---------+-----+----+
```